# React Router does not resolving on parameters route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router-dom` V6

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/">
      <Route path="example" element={<h1>Example</h1>}>
        <Route path=":id" element={<p>cool</p>} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

`"http://localhost:3000/example "` renders Example so far good, but
`"https://localhost:3000/example/34"` renders nothing.

What is the problem?

Please provide a why and how to solve this issue.

Comment: add exact property. <Route path="example" element={<h1>Example</h1>} exact>

Comment: Tqs,  but not working

Comment: Try adding index. <Route path="example" element={<h1>Example</h1>} index>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When nesting routes, the parent routes need to render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render their `element` content into. `Route` components render an `Outlet` by default when no `element` prop is provided, so this is why the `"/example"` route works.

Example:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from 'react-router-dom';

...

<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/">
      <Route
        path="example"
        element={(
          <>
            <h1>Example</h1>
            <Outlet />
          </>
        )}
      >
        <Route path=":id" element={<p>cool</p>} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

If you don't want to render the "Example" component at the same time as its children, then render it alone on its own index route.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/">
      <Route path="example">
        <Route index element={<h1>Example</h1>} />
        <Route path=":id" element={<p>cool</p>} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

For more details, see:

- [Routes and Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#routes-and-route)
- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#outlet)